# Updated entry applies to all entries in C# forms

Tags: c#, database, winforms, datagridview, crud

I have 5 forms. The 5th form lets me update an entry in a database. The problem is that once I'm finished editing with an entry and click on ***Update*** button, all of the other entries in the database will be the same as the edited entry. So for example, I edited the first name of "Mark" to "John". Once I click on ***Update***, all of my other entries also become "John" and John's info like empno and department are also applied to the other entries. What did I do wrong?

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace OOP_Draft
{
    public partial class Form5 : Form
    {
        public Form5()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitDataGrid();
        }
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Kim\Documents\SMEMCO.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
       
        private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void dgvUpdate_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void InitDataGrid()
        {
            con.Open();
            var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM LoanRecord", con);
            var dtbl = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dtbl);
            dgvUpdate.DataSource = dtbl;
        }

        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from LoanRecord where EmployeeName ='"+txtName.Text+"'", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            InitDataGrid();
            MessageBox.Show("Data sucessfully deleted to database.");
        }

        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string query = "UPDATE LoanRecord SET EmployeeName ='"+txtName.Text+"',EmployeeNumber='"+txtEmpno.Text+"',Department='"+txtDept.Text+"',LoanAmount='"+txtAmount.Text+"',YearsToPay='"+txtYears.Text+"',MonthlyPayment='"+txtMonth.Text+"',TotalPayment='"+txtOverall.Text+"'";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
            da.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            InitDataGrid();
            MessageBox.Show("Data sucessfully updated to database.");
        }

        private void dgvUpdate_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            txtName.Text = dgvUpdate.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            txtEmpno.Text = dgvUpdate.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            txtDept.Text = dgvUpdate.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            txtAmount.Text = dgvUpdate.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            txtYears.Text = dgvUpdate.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            txtMonth.Text = dgvUpdate.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            txtOverall.Text = dgvUpdate.SelectedRows[0].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        }

        private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtName.Clear();
            txtEmpno.Clear();
            txtEmail.Clear();
            txtDept.Clear();
            txtAmount.Clear();
            txtYears.Clear();
            txtMonth.Clear();
            txtOverall.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

[Changing Kim's name to Claire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r96Po.png)

[All entries became Claire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0nMv.png)

Comment: You're missing the `where` clause that specifies the `Employee` ID (you should have an ID, not a Name, to single it out, right?). You should really use Parameters, not concatenate strings. Also, you should not store the Connection object, but declare it in-place and dispose of it along with all other disposable objects you create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `where` clause to your update statement

```
// add where clause,  otherwise the following will update the entire table
string query = "UPDATE LoanRecord SET EmployeeName ='"+txtName.Text+"',EmployeeNumber='"+txtEmpno.Text+"',Department='"+txtDept.Text+"',LoanAmount='"+txtAmount.Text+"',YearsToPay='"+txtYears.Text+"',MonthlyPayment='"+txtMonth.Text+"',TotalPayment='"+txtOverall.Text+"' where someId = @idParam";
```

Don't forget to add by using parameters for all updates values. Your code is vulnerable to sql injection right now.

Check the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1